# JFrame setContentPane hides other components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

So I'm going into GUI's in Java, and am trying to create a simple main menu for a timer. All is well until I've attempted to add a background for the GUI. Adding the background works, however all other components are now gone, (the button). How could I fix this?

EDIT: Here is my new code.

public class MainMenu {

```
// JFrame = the actual menu / frame.
private JFrame frame;
// JLabel = provides text instructions or information on a GUI —
// display a single line of read-only text, an image or both text and an image.
private JLabel background;
// JButton = button.
private JButton alarmClockButton;

// Constructor to create menu
public MainMenu() {
    frame = new JFrame("Alarm Clock");
    alarmClockButton = new JButton("Timer");
    // Add an event to clicking the button.
    alarmClockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO: CHANGE TO SOMETHING NICER
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This feature hasn't been implemented yet.", "We're sorry!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
    // Creating the background
    try {
        background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass()
                .getResourceAsStream("/me/devy/alarm/clock/resources/Background.jpg"))));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(background);
    frame.add(alarmClockButton);
    frame.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(450, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    alarmClockButton.setForeground(Color.RED);
}
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: You are setting the content pane to be a JLabel. Then you call frame.add(panel), but that just tries to add panel to the content pane - you can't add a panel to a JLabel.

Comment: You might want to put that into answer form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
frame.setContentPane(background);
```

You use the label as the content pane. The problem is that the label doesn't use a layout manager by default.

You need to add:

```
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // or whatever layout you want
frame.setContentPane(background);
```

Now you can add the button directly to the frame. You don't need the panel.

Or if you want to get fancy you can use the [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) which gives you the option to scale or tile the background image.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the main post with my new code, it still seems to be having the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @TheCoder24, you haven't done what I suggested. Why are you setting the layout of the frame? Did I not suggest to set the layout of the background? You want the label to be the background so you need to make it the content pane of the frame before you add any components to the frame.

Comment: ahh my mistake, sorry about that! It now works. Do you mind explaning what exactly .setContentPane(); even does? As I have no idea. Thanks!

Comment: @TheCoder24, `Do you mind explaning what exactly .setContentPane(); even does?` - Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for an overview of how a content pane is used in a frame. I suggest you bookmark the tutorial for future reference for Swing basics.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the ContentPane as JLabel, you can wrap the JLabel in a JPanel, then add this JPanel as the ContentPane :

```
    public class MainMenu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainMenu();
    }

    // JFrame = the actual menu / frame.
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel bkgPanel;
    // JLabel = provides text instructions or information on a GUI —
    // display a single line of read-only text, an image or both text and an
    // image.
    private JLabel background;
    // JButton = button.
    private JButton alarmClockButton;

    // Constructor to create menu
    public MainMenu() {
        frame = new JFrame("Alarm Clock");
        panel = new JPanel();
        bkgPanel = new JPanel();
        alarmClockButton = new JButton("Timer");
        // Add an event to clicking the button.
        alarmClockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO: CHANGE TO SOMETHING NICER
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This feature hasn't been implemented yet.", "We're sorry!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        // Creating the background
        try {
            background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                    ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/me/devy/alarm/clock/resources/Background.jpg"))));
            bkgPanel.add(background);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        frame.setContentPane(bkgPanel);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(alarmClockButton);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(450, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        alarmClockButton.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not really a background image, though. Since the `bkgPanel` has a `FlowLayout` as layout , `panel` is being added next to the image, not on top of it.